# Searching a userID and returning the name on that line

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm using Linux and I'm new to coding and I need help with a project.

```
#!/bin/bash
# findName.sh - written by Corey Brown
#
# for use in some project
File="/acct/common/CSCE215-Fall17"

if [[ $1 = "" ]] ; then
    echo "usage: `basename $0` [only_one_argument]"
    exit 2
fi

# read the file line by line
while read LINE
do
    # file format: First, Middle, Last, UserID
    # set the index values based on the line format given above
    firstNameIndex=0
    middleNameIndex=1
    lastNameIndex=2
    userIDIndex=3

    # read the line into an array
    IFS=', ' read -r -a lineArray <<< "$LINE"

    # if the passed parameter equals the value of the line at userIDIndex
    if [[ $1 -eq ${lineArray[$userIDIndex]} ]] ; then
        echo ${lineArray[$firstNameIndex]} ${lineArray[$middleNameIndex]} ${lineArray[$lastNameIndex]}
        exit 1
    fi

done < "$File"
```

The goal is to search a userID and it finds the name associated with it. the format of the file I am searching is `FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,UserID`. There are 78 lines all with a different userID and name. This is the file:

```
Adarius,Macarthy,Adams,adamsam9
Ahmed,Abdulkarim,Hulwe,ahmedh
Ainsley,Grace,McWaters,mcwatera
Alexander,Steven,Hammett,hammeta
Allison,Rose,Rogers,arr2
Andrew,Robert,Tant,atant
Ashton,Nathaniel,Bass,anbass
Austin,Michael,Aguilera,ama4
Austin,Thomas,Blackwell,atb
Ayla,Beth,Nickerson,aylan
Bennett,Steven,Marra,bmarra
Brennan,Sanders,Cain,bscain
Brian,William,Greene,bwgreene
Byron,Javier,Carranza,carranza
Cardi,Stone,Ireland,cireland
Chad,Allen,Kraus,ckraus
Chandni,Bhavesh,Amin,camin
Chase,Michael,Henry,chasemh
Christian,Alexander,Brock,cab11
Christofer,Thomas,Cooper,cooperct
Christopher,Gregory,Masselli,masselli
Cody,James,Rose,cjrose
Colby,Franklin,McHugh,cmchugh
Cole,Peiffer,Kirby,cpkirby
Connor,Niles,Latterell,cnl
Conrad,Joseph,Hetzer,chetzer
Corey,Daniel,Brown,browncd4
Curtis,Allen,Ward,curtisaw
Dajshan,Montrel,Murphy,dajshan
Damion,Ray'shard,Graham,drgraham
Denzel,Malik,Wilson,dmwilson
Derek,,Hebert,dhebert
DeVonte,,Lyles,dlyles
D'mitri,Lamont,Williams,dmitri
Dorothy,Candra,Joyner,dcjoyner
Drew,Graham,Bussey,dgbussey
Edward,A,Perreyclear,perreyce
Emmett,Poindexter,Hatcher,ehatcher
Eric,Wayne,Davies,ewdavies
Frances,Leah,Dickson-Vandervelde,fld1
Hayley,Cy,Lichtenfels,hayleyl
Hendrick,Samuel,McCullar,hsm1
Hunter,Jarrett,Damron,hdamron
Ibrahim,J,Salman,ijsalman
Jahred,Elisha,Danker,jdanker
James,Wade,Curlee,jcurlee
Jared,Edward,Elliott,jarede
John,M,Lee,jml4
Jonathan,,Isaac,ji7
Joseph,Chambers,Martin,jcm5
Kaitlyn,Marie,Ash,kmash
Kristeen,Elizabeth,Ginn,keginn
Kunj,Girish,Naik,kgnaik
Logan,Robert,Orr,lrorr
Luke,Ellison,Whittle,whittlel
Luke,Joseph,Imholz,limholz
Mackenzie,Carter,West,mcw3
Matthew,Robert,Lassiter,lassitm
Matthew,Thomas,O'Neill,mtoneill
Nathaniel,James,Mills,njmills
Nicole,,Dorney,ndorney
Pranav,Raghu,Minasandram,pranavm
Ralph,Tristin,DeFilio,rdefilio
Robert,Brogdon,Gamble,rbgamble
Rohan,,Bhandari,rohanb
Silas,,Steiger,ssteiger
Steven,Edward,Maxwell,sem15
Steven,George,Edwards,stevenge
Suzanne,Terese,Prentice,suzannep
Taylor,Aric,Gordon,tag2
Thomas,Matthew,Sullivan,tms3
Vincent,Cordell,Arceo,varceo
Wade,Christopher,Lewis,wclewis
Wade,Prescott,Morgan,wpmorgan
William,Alexander,Simmons,wsimmons
William,Dale,Hudson,whudson
Zachary,Dylan,Smith,zds
Zachary,Paul,Stump,zstump
```

So that's the code, now when I run the script and pass in an argument it will always give me the first line in the list:

```
$ ./findName.sh zds
$ Adarius Macarthy Adams
$
```

and when I don't pass an argument it prints out the entire list. I'm taking in the indices but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `-eq` is for numeric comparison. Use `=` for string comparison.

Comment: `while IFS=, read first middle last userid; do ...`

Comment: `findName() { grep ",${1:?Need username}\$" names | awk -F, '{print $1" "$2" "$3}'; }` You might consider using pre-built tools to accomplish the goal.

Comment: Or, `awk -F, '$NF == userid {print $1,$2,$3; exit}' userid="$1" names`

Comment: @glennjackman thankyou so much I can't believe it was something as simple as a wrong comparison

Comment: @bishop I think I did this the long way and I'm not exactly searching for the word. the code that you gave, where does that go? Can you show me where in the code that fits in?